# Create lists python

Tags: python, list, function, list-comprehension

I need to build within a function in python so many lists as indicates a parameter of the function given as one of its argument, which is a positive integer. How do I do this in python by means a loop or a list comprehension?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Given a number `n` as a parameter, do you want to create a list of `n` lists?

Comment: You mean `for i in range(0, input): list()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this would do what you want:

```
def makelists(list_count):
    list_of_lists = []
    for _ in range(list_count):
        list_of_lists.append(list())
    return list_of_lists
```

Or with a list comprehension:

```
def makelists(list_count):
    return [[] for _ in range(list_count)]
```

If you're using Python 2, use `xrange` (in 2, it avoids creating a full list in memory of the `range`.) For example:

```
def makelists_py2(list_count):
    return [[] for _ in xrange(list_count)]
```

I'm using `_` as a throwaway variable since the `range` (and `xrange`) both return incrementing integers that we're not using.

Comment: You mean `[[] for _ in xrange(list_count)]`?

Comment: close, xrange only works in Python 2, but range works in both, 2 and 3, if suboptimal for 2.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
def make_lists(n):
   return [[] for _ in range(n)]
```

This creates a list of `n` empty lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `[[]] * n`. This does exactly what you're asking for, but it may not behave the way you'd expect:

```
>>> my_list = [[]] * 7
>>> my_list
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> my_list[0].append('foo')
>>> my_list
[['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo']]
```

Comment: @YábirGarcia it does NOT do what you think it does, they're all the same list, so editing one edits them all.

Comment: Side note, what's the standard protocol here for a given answer that's wrong, but an interesting tidbit comes from why it's wrong? Do I leave the answer up with the comments as is or do I delete it?

Comment: @BradBeattie up to you. Your answer is not wrong, because OP failed to be specific enough. However your answer is also not what the majority of the users would assume the OP was looking for